# if/else, good design

Tags: c#, if-statement

Is it acceptable/good-style to simplify this function:

```
bool TryDo(Class1 obj, SomeEnum type)
{
    if (obj.CanDo(type))
    {
        return Do(obj);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

as:

```
bool TryDo(Class1 obj, SomeEnum type)
{
    return obj.CanDo(type) && Do(obj);
}
```

The second version is shorter but arguably less intuitive.

Comment: Whatever makes it easy to read and maintain is the "best" way.

Comment: It depends: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/01/style-follows-semantics.aspx

Comment: @XSaint Good job stating the obvious, now the real question is which one is easier to read and maintain. The latter is very well explained in Jason's link!

Comment: @romkyns - My point is that, much like physical beauty, code beauty is in the eye of the beholder. If he will be reading/maintaining this code, then he should choose whichever option looks and feels most natural to him.

Comment: I would remove the parentheses around the return expression

Comment: I found the second version more readable : only return true if it can be done and if it returns true, otherwise return false. I also would remove the () around the return values

Comment: The only thing for me is that I don't usually expect boolean logic to have side effects (`Do`), though in this case it's short and quite obvious from `TryDo`.

Comment: Also think about how hard it is to set breakpoints.

Comment: A lot depends on how much code you have like this in your code base, try to keep it all looking the some when it does the same

Comment: I disagree with those who prefer the latter.  The argument that "if he will be reading/maintaining this code, then he should choose whichever options looks and feels most natural to him" is only true if the code is not being developed professionally; otherwise, the coder should choose the form that is easiest to read by the most number of coders.  Additionally, the latter example renders breakpoints/debugging useless.  Futhermore, the latter example does not allow easy future tweaking.  The former is superior for all of these reasons.

Comment: First: maintainable. Second: slick

Answer (score 65, accepted):

What I would code is :

```
return obj.CanDo(type) ? Do(obj) : false;
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far. It is short but equivalent to the if/else (not just functionally equivalent, but semantically too). The only criticism I have is that I would remove the redundant parentheses.

Comment: This is slick and a nice one-line solution, but not very readable at all.

Comment: I don't see why people gate on that ternary conditional.  Looks good to me!

Comment: @Zann readability depends strongly on practice. It's readable to everyone who has practiced reading this operator - which many programmers have. Readability of code is a rather elusive goal because of this...

Comment: @jon_darkstar: Looks fine to me too.

Comment: It takes a little to get used to, but ternary conditionals are very nice to read. They are clear and let you know what it's going to do at a glance.

Comment: @Zann not slow, no. You just need practice. Use this operator a few times and you'll soon start seeing immediately what's going on.

Comment: @Zann - I have a man crush on the ternary operator and always have.  Given the opportunity to use it, I will (in all cases).  It's an automatic for me; it's use is simple, elegant and straightforward.

Comment: *Please* remove the extra parentheses

Comment: jon_darkstar: Because visually, it's nearly transparent.  I can glance at a line with even a very short keyword like `if` and identify the pieces easily, but `?` and `:` easily get lost in the noise, especially with all the `()` that are typically needed.  I'm a huge fan of the expressiveness of `?:` (and, being a Lisp and Ruby programmer I think having an if statement at all is kind of dumb), but I do find it visually hard to read `?:`.

Comment: @Ken: I would agree if the statement was complicated. That is a pretty simple ternary conditional. Our standard is to avoid ternary conditionals if they need to span multiple lines.

Comment: Juan: I think that `?:` expressions that span multiple lines are *far easier* to read, because you can use line breaks to separate each of the 3 expressions, and (like if-expressions in other languages) they're just so dang useful.  Like a line beginning with `if` or `else`, a line beginning with `?` or `:` is easy to identify without reading the whole line.  With this one-line return statement, I have to mentally parse the entire line to know it's generally going to return the result of `Do(obj)`, buried in the middle.

Comment: romkyns: I've been seeing and using this operator pretty regularly for about 20 years.  How much more practice do I need before these stop being harder to read?

Comment: @Ken, I am not trying to be cute here, but if you feel after 20 years that they are still hard to read, why do you continue to use them?

Comment: Is this the most overrated answer on StackOverflow? (Overrated meaning highest number of upvotes for an answer that is completely and utterly wrong?) This is less clear than the alternatives, not debugger friendly, and a maintainability disaster.

Comment: @Jason - explain how it's 'completely and uttterly wrong' - to a neophyte this operator can look unusual but to an experienced developer it's simple, elegant (and a breeze to debug) - P.S. did you also downvote Guffa's answer?

Comment: John: The easy answer is: when I see it in someone else's code, I'm not going to rewrite it to avoid this construct, so I have to work with them.  But sometimes I do write it myself, because it's the semantic equivalent of an if-expression, which is what I really want (in Ruby, which has both, I never use `?:`).  And, truth be told, sometimes I like saving a few lines, when I'm confident it's correct, won't need to be changed, an it's wrapped inside an abstraction, even at the cost of a little localized readability.  If my coworkers think that `?:` is readable, am I really a bad person? ;-)

Comment: @timwi Because it's cryptic

Answer (score 25):

Version with brackets:

```
bool TryDo(Class1 obj, SomeEnum type)
{
    if (obj.CanDo(type))
    {
        return Do(obj);
    }

    return false;
}
```

<strike>Or version without brackets (in answer comments is high debate about it):</strike>

```
bool TryDo(Class1 obj, SomeEnum type)
{
    /*
     * If you want use this syntax of
     * "if", this doing this on self
     * responsibility, and i don't want
     * get down votes for this syntax,
     * because if I remove this from my
     * answer, i get down votes because many
     * peoples think brackets i wrong.
     * See comments for more information.
     */
    if (obj.CanDo(type))
        return Do(obj);

    return false;
}
```

Your first code example is better, but I think my version is even better.

Your **second version is not good readable and makes code harder to maintain**, this is bad.

Comment: I like this version best. You could also remove the braces from the if-block to compact it a little more, but some people really dislike that.

Comment: @CodexArcanum: yes i dislike this.

Comment: @Svisstack: can you please give arguments to justify your last sentence? I think it’s flat wrong.

Comment: @CodexArcanum: I took from a settings of C++ standards that, if you have an if with a single statement, you could remove braces **and** inline the statement. I find that it's more readable.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: can you explain why?

Comment: It's generally bad practice to leave braces off of if blocks, both for readability and maintainability.

Comment: @Svisstack - it's less clear what exactly is and isn't part of the if block without the braces.  Furthermore, if somebody comes along and adds code that's meant for the if block but misses adding the braces, you've now got a bug.

Comment: @Svisstack: It’s your claim, the onus is on *you* to explain. But for what it’s worth the code only uses core language constructs in their usual meaning, notably without employing any trickery that might render this code non-intuitive. – Apart from that I also find *your* proposed code quite readable and definitely more acceptable than the original first variant.

Comment: @Zannjaminderson: i know this but i added because answer comments suggest it. But i removed this now because i see the many people have same practices like me.

Comment: @Zannjaminderson: that point is debatable. There is no consensus that leaving the braces off is bad. It certainly isn’t “bad practice”. If someone comes along and adds code, they also add the braces. Forgetting that isn’t a common mistake, in my experience.

Comment: My opinion is keeping braces for single code line is C# style while leaving is C++ one

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph - ok, maybe "bad practice" was the wrong phrase - how about "less accepted"?  Or maybe "most people would say don't do this"?

Comment: @Zann: that would require taking a vote. I don’t think it’s obvious that this style of code is less acceptable. In fact, I personally find it *preferable* to always putting the braces because like Jeff Atwood I experience screen space as a real estate and I hate wasting it with redundant empty lines (which are here introduced by the closing brace).

Comment: @Zannjaminderson: I do not get the impression that it is “less accepted” and that “most people would say don’t do this” — but even if that were the case, it would *still* not follow that you shouldn’t do it (that would just be blind social conformity). What I *do* find is that the ones who are most vocal about wanting the brackets in, tend to be relatively new to programming — which might also explain why they argue about the mistake of forgetting to put the brackets in when you need them, a mistake that a reasonably experienced programmer would not make.

Comment: @Konrad - from much of the code I've seen (at least C#), single-line if blocks have braces.  Also, in style guides that I've seen or for companies I've worked for, braces for single-line if blocks are encouraged.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that forgetting the `return` inside the `if` can lead to a rather insipid bug because the code will still compile, whereas always ensuring there is an `else` case and adding the `return false` inside that means the code won't compile if you forget the `return` for the `if` clause. Adding `else` is a better coding style for avoiding costly bugs.

Comment: @Konrad - if you want a vote, why not check out http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no

Comment: Anyone else think having multiple returns is just bad practice?  Sure this is short concise and easy to see both but when we are takling about a long method/function with lots of if/else statements I feel it best to have one place to return.

Comment: @Chris - I prefer exiting a method as soon as possible and reducing nested statements.

Answer (score 18):

The `else` is useless and the `&&`, however obvious, is not as readable as pure text.

I prefer the following:

```
bool TryDo(Class1 obj, SomeEnum type)
{
    if (obj.CanDo(type))
    {
        return Do(obj);
    }   
    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 I was just about to post this exact method. I hate when all the returns are nested. It makes it less obvious that it "always" returns something, esp for the compiler.

Answer (score 13):

Yes.

Especially with names similar to your chosen names, i.e. `CanDoSomething` and `DoSomething` it is **absolutely clear** to any competent programmer what the second code does: “*if and only if* the condition holds, do something and return the result”. “if and only if” is the core meaning of the short-circuited `&&` operator.

The first code is convoluted and unnecessarily long without giving any more information than the second code.

But in general, the two conditions may not form such an intimate relationship (as in `CanDo` and `Do`) and it might be better to separate them logically because putting them in the same conditional might not make intuitive sense.

A lot of people here claim that the first version is “much clearer”. I’d really like to hear their arguments. I can’t think of any.

On the other hand, there’s this closely related (although not *quite* the same) code:

```
if (condition)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

this should **always** be transformed to this:

```
return condition;
```

**No exception**. It’s concise and still more readable to someone who is competent in the language.

Comment: Yes but OP want return something else, not condition result.

Comment: Many programmers are not fully competent, any many more must deal with multiple languages over time where logical operators are sometimes handled differently. For this reason, I think the 2nd block is safer, if not clearer.

Comment: @kaliatech: there’s a long shot between being “fully competent” and understanding the language basics. And I argue (strongly!) that we cannot always cater to beginners in clean code because the result will be convoluted, complicated and ultimately hard to maintain for professionals. If not for any other reason then because of the sheer code size. Yes, code size *does* matter.

Comment: I like this answer (+1), though I am not sure that it is the correct one in a C# context. In C++ I would have no doubts. Relaying on well known language constructs and idioms improves clarity, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree. The second is no harder to understand than the first, and the first has the disadvantage of being longer. I think code should be clear and consise. The second example meets both of those conditions.

Answer (score 12):

The shortened version hides the fact that Do does something. It looks like you're just doing a comparison and returning the result, but you're actually doing a comparison and performing an action, and it's not obvious that the code has this "side effect".

I think the core of the problem is that you're returning the result of an evaluation and the return code of an action. If you were returning the result of two evaluations in this way, I wouldn't have a problem with it

Comment: One more reason to choose good method names. If the method names are as clear as in the example, the fact that `Do` does something is very hard to hide. Furthermore, there is *no comparison* in the code.

Comment: Comparison was probably a bit lazy, I grant you, though the && is effectively doing a bit wise comparison, so...   I agree the method names would certainly help, but I'd still consider this a refactor too far

Comment: “bitwise comparison”? What’s that? There is no IL instruction that is commonly described that way. Both `? :` and `&&` only ever compile into a `brtrue` or `brfalse` instruction, never a `bgt`, `beq`, etc., and most certainly not anything that is commonly called “bitwise” (such as `and`, which is not a comparison but an arithmetic instruction).

Comment: Damn it, lazy in my explanation of why I was lazy!! Bitwise was completely irrelevant - I meant comparing the two booleans. Perhaps I need a lie down...

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative that may be a bit more readable is using the conditional operator:

```
bool TryDo(Class1 obj, SomeEnum type) {
  return obj.CanDo(type) ? Do(obj) : false;
}
```

Comment: only if the conditional operator is used a lot in your code base.

Comment: (it may depend on language but) I believe the correct term for that is "ternary operator"

Comment: @John Isaacks: The term "ternary operator" only specifies that it's an operator that has three operands, while the term "conditional operator" specifies exactly what operator it is. In C# there is only one operator with three operands, but I still find it more useful to use a term that describes what the operator does, not only how many operators it uses. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Answer (score 6):

The 1st version is much easier to read with less chance of being misunderstood, and I think that is important in real world code.

Answer (score 6):

I do not like this design, and maybe not for the obvious reason.  What bothers me is.
return Do(obj);
To me it makes no sense for the Do function to have a bool return type.  Is this a substitute for property pushing errors up?
Most likely this function should be void or returning a complex object.  The scenario should simply not come up.
Also if a bool somehow makes sense now, it can easily stop making sense in the future.  With your code change it would require more re factoring to fix

Comment: Absolutely disagree. A method that has side-effects and returns a bool is completely normal and comes up all the time. Consider, for example, `bool HashSet<T>.Add()`. Your criticism makes too many assumptions about the OP’s code structure — from what little we’ve seen of it, it is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Good points. I guess i would want that function called TryDo()  Also in a way i am saying something similar to Kevin O'Donovan

Answer (score 5):

In this case, I would go with the first option - it is *much* more readable and the intention of the code is *much* clearer.

Answer (score 5):

Neither, because when TryDo returns False, you can't determine whether it was because
'Not CanDo' or 'Do returned False'.

I fully understand that you can ignore the result, but the way it's expressed implies that the result has meaning.

If the result is meaningless, the intent would be clearer with

```
void TryDo(Class1 obj, SomeEnum type)
{
    if (obj.CanDo(type))
        Do(obj);
    return;
}
```

If the result does have a meaning then there should be a way to differentiate between the two 'false' returns. I.E. What does 'If (!TryDo(x))' *mean*?

Edit: To put it another way, the OP's code is saying that 'I can't swim' is the same as 'I tried to swim and drowned'

Answer (score 4):

While it is certainly clear what the second code for a competent programmer, it would seem to me clearer and easier to read in a more general case to write the code like any other "if precondition satisfied, do action, else fail" style.

This could be achieved either by:

```
return obj.CanDo(type)? Do(obj) : false;
```

Or,

```
if(obj.CanDo(type)) return Do(obj);
return false;
```

I find this superior because this same style can be replicated no matter the return type. For example,

```
return (array.Length > 1)? array[0] : null;
```

Or,

```
return (curActivity != null)? curActivity.Operate() : 0;
```

The same style can also be expanded to situations that don't have a return value:

```
if(curSelection != null)
    curSelection.DoSomething();
```

My two cents.

Answer (score 4):

I don't like the second version as I'm not really a fan of taking advantage of the order of sub-expression evaluation in a conditional expression. It's placing an expected ordering on sub-expressions which in my mind, should have equal precedence (even though they don't).

At the same time, I find the first version a bit bloated, so I'd opt for the ternary solution which I consider highly readable.

Answer (score 4):

IMO it's only OK if the second function has no side-effects. But since Do() has side-effects I'd go with the if.

My guideline is that an expression should not have side-effekts. When calling functions with a side-effect use a statement.
This guideline has a problem if a function returns a failurecode. In that case I accept assignment of that errorcode to a variable or directly returning it. But I don't use the return value in a complex expression. So perhaps I should say that only the outermost function call in an expression should have a side-effect.

See [Eric Lippert's Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20100822225551/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/01/style-follows-semantics.aspx) for a longer explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The side-effect problem that some people are mentioning is bogus. No one should be surprised that a method named "Do" has a side-effect.

The fact is, you are calling two methods. Both of those methods have bool as a return value. Your second option is very clear and concise. (Though I would get rid of the outer parenthesis and you forgot an ending semi-colon.)

Answer (score 1):

Never do that. Keep it simple and intuitive.

Comment: The second code *is* simple and intuitive. If you disagree, please explain.

Comment: simple as in easy to understand and maintain

Comment: @Liviu: well then: the code *is* easy to understand and maintain. If you disagree, please explain.

Comment: Look at the other posts on this thread and see for yourself, consider those answers my explanation.

Comment: @Liviu: that’s the point though. They don’t explain either. :-(

Comment: I don't think it is easy to maintain. Since when I glance at the expression with && I wouldn't expect a side-effect.

Answer (score 1):

I might get hate for this but what about:

```
if (obj.CanDo(type)) return Do(obj);
return false;
```

I don't like having braces for one liners.

Comment: Not only does that have a redundant else, but it is very hard to read.

Comment: @CrapHands Removed the else, though for me that makes it a bit less readable since my brain is basically adding an else there anyway.

Comment: I don't like putting the then part of the if on the same line as the if. Just add a linebreak before the `return DO()`

Answer (score 1):

I think that the Class1 Type should determine if it can do, given a SomeEnum value.

I would leave the decision on whether or not it can handle the input for it to decide:

```
bool TryDo(Class1 obj, SomeEnum type)
{
    return obj.Do(type));    
}
```

Comment: But then the call to Do(obj) is lost

Comment: @KevinDTimm Correct, I meant to have the return be return obj.Do(type)); obj should decide if it can or not fulfil the task, return false otherwise

Answer (score 1):

For me, I prefer the second method. Most of my methods that return bool are shortened in the same manner when simple conditional logic is involved.

Answer (score 1):

No. The second version

```
return (obj.CanDo(type) && Do(obj))
```

relies on the short-circuiting behavior of the && operator which is an optimization, not a method to control program flow. In my mind this is only slightly different than using exceptions for program flow (and almost as bad).

I hate clever code, it's a bitch to understand and debug. The goal of the function is "if we can do this, then do it and return the result else return false." The original code makes that meaning very clear.

Comment: you have misunderstood the purpose of short-circuiting. It’s *not* primarily an optimization (if at all, this is just a side-effect). Consequently, your whole argument is wrong.

Comment: @Konrad - what makes you say that? It's certainly an optimization, I assume it was intended as such but don't know. I am certain that it was not intended to control program flow.

Answer (score 1):

There are several good answers already, but I thought I would show one more example of (what I consider) good, readable code.

```
bool TryDo(Class1 obj, SomeEnum type)
{
    bool result = false;

    if (obj.CanDo(type))
    {
        result = Do(obj);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Keep or remove the curly brackets back around the body of the if statement according to taste.

I like this approach because it illustrates that the result is `false` unless something else happens, and I think it more clearly shows that `Do()` is doing something and returning a boolean, which `TryDo()` uses as its return value.

Comment: I agree you! At the same time it allows you the set up a "default" return value and having one exit point it will be very easy to debug as well